# Trying to access response globally

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swift, alamofire

I'm using Alamofire and when I get the response I'm trying to set it as a variable that I can access anywhere. Here's what I got going

```
var data: NSData?
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost/api/notifications", parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
           let data: AnyObject? = JSON
    }
println(data)
```

And when I run that I get `nil`.... Any ideas? I know that the request is good because I can see the response inside the scope when I don't assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Almofire.request` is an asynchronous function. You call it and it will return immediately; before it actually does the request. So, `println(data)` gets called before anything ever sets `data` to something other than `nil`. When the request is actually complete, Alamofire will call the closure you pass to `responseJSON`, in that closure is where you'll want to actually use `data` (print it or whatever):

```
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost/api/notifications", parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
        let data: AnyObject? = JSON
        // do something useful with data
        println(data)
    }
```

---

**Question from comments:**

> But then lets say I want to turn that data into a table. Would I just put all the table code inside the closure?

You *could* put all that code inside the closure, but that will probably get messy pretty quickly. A better way to handle that is to implement the same sort of pattern that `Alamofire.request` is using. Basically, make your request its own function will takes a closure as a parameter. Then, in the closure you pass to `responseJSON`, call the closure passed to your function passing it `data`. Then, make a separate function to "turn that data into a table" and call it with `data` from your closure. Something like this:

```
func callSomeAPI(resultHandler: (data: AnyObject?) -> ()) -> () {
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost/api/notifications", parameters: parameters)
        .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
           let data: AnyObject? = JSON
           resultHandler(data)
    }
}

func makeTable(data: AnyObject?) -> () {
    // make your table
}

callSomeAPI() { data in
    makeTable(data)
}
```

***Note:** You'll probably want to convert `data` to something other than `AnyObject?` at some point in there.*

Comment: So you're saying I can't access the `data` constant outside of the `.responseJSON`?....

Comment: It's not really that you can't access it, it's that it won't be set until after the closure passed to `responseJSON` is called. Since the request will be made asynchronously, `data` won't be set when you're currently trying to call it. If I knew more about what you want to do with `data` (other than print it) after it's set, I might be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: `data` is the JSON response. I want to take that JSON and print it out "pretty". Like `Name: Bob`, or `Age: 22`. Not `{ -data:[Name: Bob, Age: "22"]}` Understand?

Comment: Ok, if you really just want to print it, and nothing else, then simply putting the `println` statement inside the closure should do what you want.

Comment: But then lets say I want to turn that data into a table. Would I just put all the table code inside the closure?

Answer (score -1):

It is because when you do `let data: AnyObject? = JSON` you created a new local variable `data` in the closure.

You should do this instead:

```
var data: NSData?
Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://localhost/api/notifications", parameters: parameters)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, JSON, error) in
           data = JSON 
    }
println(data)
```

Comment: That will also print `nil`, but for a different reason.

Comment: I did `data = JSON as? NSData`, and when printing I still get `nil`, followed by `(lldb)` @AaronBrager

Comment: Yes, that's because the data hasn't been received by the time you're trying to print it.

Comment: Also you should declare `data` as a Dictionary, not `NSData`.

Comment: Well I'm trying to print _after_ I set `data = JSON as? NSDictionary`. I'm not sure what else to do when you say it's not received in time. This is the first time i've worked with HTTP and Swift, so sorry for being so basic. @AaronBrager